# permission denied when executing binary despite "rwx" privilege and root user

Tags: permissions, executable

I'm trying to execute some binary with `bash`. I am getting a "Permission denied" message despite having given the full privileges (`chmod 777`) and being the 'root' user:

This is the file description:

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 641K Aug 22 15:04 wrapid
```

This is the error message:

```
bash: ./wrapid: Permission denied
```

Output of `strace ./wrapid`:

```
execve("./wrapid", ["./wrapid"], [/* 13 vars */]) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
write(2, "strace: exec: Permission denied\n", 32strace: exec: Permission denied ) = 32
exit_group(1) = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Output of `ldd ./wrapid`:

```
/usr/bin/ldd: line 104: lddlibc4: command not found not a dynamic executable
```

Output of `file wrapid`:

```
wrapid: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV),
dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32,
BuildID[sha1]=0x817251da41b3c8684a68f6f4afa1b4cd8f116072, not stripped
```

Output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux WR-IntelligentDevice 3.4.43-grsec-WR5.0.1.7_standard #2 SMP PREEMPT Thu Aug 22 16:27:28 CST 2013 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the info provided you are trying to run 64-bit executable on 32-bit kernel. It won't work that way. You either need 32-bit binary or 64-bit kernel/glibc libraries.