# Unable to execute certain programs even as root

Tags: linux, permissions

I am unable to execute certain programs in various folders even as root. The programs have the correct permissions on them. For example see below

```
[root@ODHI01VMA02 bin]# ls -la java*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 56056 May 10  2013 java
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 16674 May 10  2013 java_vm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 56056 May 10  2013 javaw
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 78842 May 10  2013 javaws
```

When I execute java I get the following error.

```
[root@ODHI01VMA02 bin]# ./java -version
bash: ./java: Permission denied

[root@ODHI01VMA02 bin]# ldd java
    not a dynamic executable
```

This one does not work,

```
[root@ODHI01VMA02 bin]# file java
java: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, not stripped
```

This one does work,

```
# file java
java: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.4.0, not stripped
```

This is not just with the above program, i just used it as an example. There are other programs on other drives that have the same issue. Also a lot of other programs work without any issues.

This is on RedHat 6.7. Any Linux Gurus please help.

Jagi

Comment: Post the output of `file java`, or any of the other programs with that issue. Also, what are the origins of the files with that problem? Did you build them yourself, and if not, where did you get them from?

Comment: [root@ODHI01VMA02 bin]# file java
java: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, not stripped           I did not build the file, it was part of WebSphere installation.

Comment: This java from a different directory works file java
java: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.4.0, not stripped

Comment: Could it be because i am missing something on the server that is required to run 32 bit programs?

Comment: Similar to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108978/4671.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your output the problem is probably that you are trying to run a 32 bit executable on a 64 bit machine which is not set up for it. You notice the one that works is 64 bit, and the one that doesn't is 32 bit.

Run `ldd java` for your two executables. And please put output in your question, not in comments.

(This is almost certainly a dupe...)